# Filling an array with asynchronous calls using Q

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, q

I have a function that returns a value asynchronously using the Q library.
And I have to call it inside a loop to fill an array with all the results.

Something like this example I've been working on (this is not working as intented, since the array is returned before being filled).

```
function fillArray(){
 var deferred = q.defer();

 var resultsArray;
 for(var i=0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
  asyncFunction(i).then(function(result){
   resultsArray.push(result);
  }
 }

 deferred.resolve(resultsArray);
 return deferred.promise;
}

function asyncFunction(number){
 var deferred = q.defer();
 deferred.resolve(number+1);
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

I've read that I can use Q.all to call several functions, but I cannot understand how to call it inside the loop.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You do not call it *in* the loop. You create an array of promises in the loop, then apply `Q.all` on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function fillArray(){
    var promises = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
        promises.push(asyncFunction(i));
    }

    return q.all(promises);
}

function asyncFunction(number){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(number+1);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

[promise.all()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) is rejected with the same rejection reason as the first promise to be rejected. This means that if some of the promises in the array are rejected, the promise returned by `all` is also rejected. You can use [promise.allSettled()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled) if you want to wait for all the original promises to be settled.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to defer fillArray as well?


Do I need to do something like `deferred.resolve(q.all(promises));`?

Comment: `q.all` already return a promise. Check the link to the docs in my answer. Since `fillArray` is returning the result of calling `q.all` all you need to do is "subscribe" to that promise `fillArray().then((resultsArray) => { /* Do something */ });`

Comment: Great, one more thing I've run into testing this.
What if I need to return an error in other part of the code in the fillArray function?

For instance, if I need to do a `deferred.reject(err)` before the q.all...

Comment: @mdlapla If at least one of the promises returned by `asyncFunction` is rejected, the promise returned by `fillArray` is also rejected. I don't see why you would explicitly return an error from the `fillArray` function. If you `fillArray` code changed, please post a new question describing your issues, and if this answer your original question please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Great, this seems to have worked, the only problem is that it returns an array of Promise objects instead of the value.

This means that I still have to translate every promise to its value somehow.

Comment: @mdlapla You can use `promise.all` or `promise.allSettled` in combination with `promise.spread` to make it easier. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisespreadonfulfilled-onrejected

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
fillArray().then(function(result){
   console.log(result);
});
```

and it worked correct.

Only thing I did extra from your code is changing

```
var resultsArray = [];
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the array will be completely populated when the promises returned by `fillArray` is resolved.